# Why does gdb run nop(0x09) twice when I input only 'stepi'?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I am doing buflab Level 4 of CSAPP and cannot get my exploit code right. When I'm debugging it using gdb, I find these:

```
(gdb) si
0x08048d0a in getbufn ()
(gdb) si
0x55683648 in _reserved ()
(gdb) si
0x5568364a in _reserved ()
(gdb) si
0x5568364c in _reserved ()
(gdb) x /x 0x5568364a
0x5568364a <_reserved+1037898>: 0x09090909
(gdb) si
0x5568364e in _reserved ()
(gdb)
```

The opcode of `nop` is 1-byte 0x09, so gdb should normally execute it byte by byte, but actually it doesn't: the address increments by 0x02 in each step. Why would this happen?

Comment: NOP is `0x90` not `0x09`. `0x09 0x09` is a two byte instruction `or [ecx], ecx`. You can use `x/i` in gdb to disassemble.

Comment: @Jester Oh I have been debugging the program for 2 days and didn't find it! Thank you so much, I have passed level 4!!!

Comment: Use `layout asm` and/or `layout reg` to have gdb show you disassembly of what you're stepping through!  You're not supposed to have to `x /x` the instruction bytes and understand the machine code yourself!  There's a bit more info about this at the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Another option if you don't like split windows: `display/3i $eip` (or `$rip` on 64-bit)